# error Parsing error: Unexpected token (Nuxt.js)

Tags: vue.js, eslint, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use the following function to control my tabs (Bulma CSS):

```
openTab(evt, tabName) {
      let i
      const x, tablinks
      x = document.getElementsByClassName('content-tab')
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = 'none'
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tab')
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(' is-active', '')
      }
      document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block'
      evt.currentTarget.className += ' is-active'
    }
```

When WebPack reloads the page I get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (330:6)                                                                friendly-errors 09:58:05

  328 |       let i
  329 |       const x
> 330 |       const tablinks
      |       ^
  331 |       x = document.getElementsByClassName('content-tab')
  332 |       for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  333 |         x[i].style.display = 'none'
```

I've tried changing const to var but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

This is my eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/vue'
  ],
  plugins: [
    'prettier'
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
  }
}
```

Anyone know what might be causing this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a value to a `const` as soon as it's declared. You can't declare it at the top and assign a value later.

So you need to write it as:

```js
const x = document.getElementsByClassName('content-tab')
```

Similar for `tablinks`.

I don't know why changing `const` to `var` wouldn't fix the problem but I'm pretty certain this is what's causing that error message. It may be that something else went wrong when you tried changing it to `var`. Without seeing the error message that was generated when you used `var` it's difficult to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, @skirtle! This has solved my problem. Really appreciate your help :)